# Unity IoC: "Operation could destabilize the runtime"

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Is it possible to instantiate a type, configured in UnityContainer, within the constructor of another type configured in UnityContainer? With my current solution, I'm getting a

> ResolutionFailedException:
>   Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Sample.IMyProcessor", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: VerificationException - Operation could destabilize the runtime.

The Problem is that my second class (*FileLoader*) has an argument which should be evaluated in the first constructor:

The Constructor of the **MyProcessor** class:

```cs
public class MyProcessor : IMyProcessor
{
    private readonly IFileLoader loader;
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public MyProcessor(IRepository repository, string environment, Func<SysConfig, IFileLoader> loaderFactory)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        SysConfig config = repository.GetConfig(environment);

        loader = loaderFactory(config);
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        loader.Process();
    }
}
```

And here the Main function with the UnityContainer config:

```cs
public static void Run()
{
    var unityContainer = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<IRepository, MyRepository>()
    .RegisterType<IFileLoader, FileLoader>()
    .RegisterType<IMyProcessor, MyProcessor>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IRepository), "DEV", typeof(Func<SysConfig, IFileLoader>)));

    //Tests
    var x = unityContainer.Resolve<IRepository>(); //--> OK
    var y = unityContainer.Resolve<IFileLoader>(); //--> OK

    var processor = unityContainer.Resolve<IMyProcessor>();
    //--> ResolutionFailedException: "Operation could destabilize the runtime."

    processor.DoWork();
}
```

And the **FileLoader** class:

```cs
public class FileLoader : IFileLoader
{
    private readonly SysConfig sysConfig;

    public FileLoader(SysConfig sysConfig, IRepository repository)
    {
        this.sysConfig = sysConfig;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        //some sample implementation
        if (sysConfig.IsProduction)
            Console.WriteLine("Production Environement");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test Environment");
    }
}
```

I assume the Problem is related to the *Func* which is passed to the MyProcessor class. Is there another way to pass the *loaderFactory* to the *MyProcessor* class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that Unity automatic factories only support `Func<T>` and not any other of the Func generics.

You could register the Func you want with Unity and then it will be resolved:

```
Func<SysConfig, IFileLoader> func = config => container.Resolve<IFileLoader>();
container.RegisterType<Func<SysConfig, IFileLoader>>(new InjectionFactory(c => func));

var processor = container.Resolve<IMyProcessor>();
```

There are some other solutions out there such as this: [Unity's automatic abstract factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652359/unitys-automatic-abstract-factory)